# How to delete a table without affecting referenced values in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, delete-row

I have a table my_tab in postgres which have many foreign key constraints .I need to delete 1.4 million records . I should not delete its foreign key constraints values in referenced tables using cascade . I am also not a super user . It takes hours to delete 1.4 million records . Can i disbale a constraint and then enable it ?

```
DELETE FROM MY_TAB WHERE COL1 = 'X_COND' AND COL2 = 'Y_COND';
```

Comment: Do you have indexes on the foreign key columns?

Comment: Are you saying `MY_TAB` has foreign key constraints referencing other tables, or that there are other tables referencing `MY_TAB`?

Comment: And (assuming the latter) are you saying that the rows in `MY_TAB` that you want to delete are not actually referenced by any rows in the other tables?

Comment: Hi Frank , yes . We have indexes

Comment: Hi Bergi , My tab table column values refer other table column values . Since I need to delete only a portion of columns which are around 1.4 million I need to delete only rows in My_ tab table not it’s referenced values

Comment: If you are deleting referenc*ing* values, not referenc*ed* values, then foreign key constraints are not applicable at all and will not slow down the query.

Comment: Please use `EXPLAIN` and [edit] your question to show us the query plan

Comment: Hi Bergi, Sure . Will do . Thanks